# UIView not resizing, is there a property I'm missing?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm trying to make a subview for a view and have it be a smaller size, however, the subview isn't resizing. I wonder if I'm missing something. The View Controller's 'viewDidLoad' code is like this:

```
[_testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

CGRect frame = self.testView.frame;
frame.size.height -= 500;
// self.testView.frame = frame;
[_testView addSubview:_testSubView];

[_testSubView setFrame:frame];
```

But no change in the subview's height is seen. Any ideas why?

Comment: Adjustments to a size of a view should be in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of the view controller, not in `viewDidLoad`. But keep the call to `addSubview:` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Looks like it should be going into 'viewDidLayoutSubviews'. When I put the re-sizing code in there, the view gets resized.

Comment: have you dealt with the `clipToBounds` property?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the "viewDidLoad" method, it's safe to assume that you are initializing this view in a nib file. If there are any constraints on this view, it is in fact possible for them to be applied to a view *after* the viewDidLoad method, because the final size of the view is not determined completely until the "viewWillAppear" method.

Long story short, try moving your frame change to the "viewWillAppear:animated:" method.

Comment: Looks like it should be going into 'viewDidLayoutSubviews'. When I put the re-sizing code in there, the view gets resized.

Answer (score 0):

Did setup autoresizingMask on your subview ?

```
_testSubView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Check that autoresizesSubviews is set on your parent view too.

```
_testView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

I think you should have a look at autolayout too.

Regards,